# Prove that $f^{-1} (I)$ is a closed set

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology

Let $I$ be a closed interval in $\mathbb{R}$. Let $f$ be a continuous function $\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow I$. Prove that $f^{-1} (I)$ is a closed set.

I know there is theorem that says this is true in general. But how can one prove this directly using the proposition: "A set is closed if and only if it contains all its limit points"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider an arbitrary a sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subset f^{-1}(I)$ converging to some $x$ and prove that $x\in f^{-1}(I)$.

Comment: OK, it's easy.. $(f(x_n))_n$ converges to $f(x)$ since $f$ is continuous. Also $f(x)\in I$ since $I$ is closed. Thus $x\in f^{-1} (I)$. Is this all? The fact that we are working in $\mathbb{R}^2$ was not relevant at all?

Comment: @luka5z: indeed, all you used was the fact that $I$ is closed, and $f$ is continuous. The preimage of any closed subset under a continuous map is closed.

Comment: @luka5z: Correct. :o)

Comment: @AlexWertheim I know, but I wasnt allowed to use this theorem yet.

Comment: He meant that you actually just proved it. ;o)